# How to export dynamically generated SCSS variables for use in React

Tags: css, sass, colors

I have a `_Variables.scss` file where I am dynamically generating all my colors.  I would like to get access to just one of those colors in my React code, instead of hard coding the value in the code.

My variables file:

```
$colors-light: (
        'color-primary': #EFEFEF,
        'color-primary-variant': #D7D7D7,
        'color-primary-variant-light': #AAAAAA,
        'color-secondary': #23805C,
        'color-secondary-variant': #009687,
        'text': #4E4E4E,
        'text-alt': #FFFFFF
);

$colors-dark: (
        'color-primary': #2F302F,
        'color-primary-variant': #4E4E4E,
        'color-primary-variant-light': #6E6E6E,
        'color-secondary': #48BF91,
        'color-secondary-variant': #009687,
        'color-header': #484e3d,
        'text': #FFFFFF,
        'text-alt': #222222,
);

/* SASS Functions to create all the CSS variables from the SASS colors above */

@function hexToRGB($hex) {
  @return red($hex), green($hex), blue($hex);
}

@mixin generate_colors($colors) {
  // Colors
  @each $color, $value in $colors {
    @if str-slice(#{$value}, 1, 1) == '#' {
      --#{$color}: #{$value};
    }
    @else {
      --#{$color}: var(--#{$value});
    }
  }

  // RGB Colors
  @each $color, $value in $colors {
    @if str-slice(#{$value}, 1, 1) == '#' {

      /* stylelint-disable function-name-case  */

      --RGB-#{$color}: #{hexToRGB($value)};

      /* stylelint-enable function-name-case  */
    }

    @else {
      --RGB_#{$color}: var(--RGB_#{$value});
    }
  }
}

/* End of SASS functions */

/* Use the SASS functions and the SASS variables to actually create all the CSS color variables;
    e.g. --color-black: #222222 and --RGB-color-black: 34, 34, 34
 */

:root[data-theme='theme-light'] {
  @include generate_colors($colors-light);

  --color-true-black: #000000;
  --RGB-color-true-black: 0, 0, 0;
  --color-white: #FFFFFF;
  --RGB-color-white: 255, 255, 255;
  //--color-orchestrator: #d0ced0;
  --color-red: #BB0000;
  --RGB-color-red: 187, 0, 0;
  --color-red-lighter: #FF2E2E;
  --color-pink: #E4BFBF;
  --RGB-color-red-lighter: 255, 46, 46;
  --color-green: #348D00;
  --color-blue: #0000CC;
  --RGB-color-blue: 0, 0, 204;
  --RGB-color-green: 52, 141, 0;
  --label-alpha: 0.3;
}

:root[data-theme='theme-dark'] {
  @include generate_colors($colors-dark);

  // this does not work
  :export {
    color-primary: var(--color-primary);
  }


  --label-alpha: 0.9;
}
```

In my `App.scss` file I import `Variables` and can use them like this:
`.answer { color: var(--color-secondary);...`

But I am trying to also export them(or just one for now) to use in my React.

Comment: Is there a technical debt that makes you have SCSS variables and Custom properties (css variables)?

Comment: @Dejan.S You're saying I have both types in that variables file?

Comment: Some projects don't have any other option while trying to migrate to new tech. I'm wondering why you want to use scss variables and convert them to css variables? One option is to migrate to use only css variables.

Comment: I didn't even realize I was doing that to be honest.  I pieced together code I found online to get it to work for me.

Comment: No worries. In your case I would just go with the custom properties (css variables). They are dynamic at runtime meaning you can change live so to speak. I would suggest checking out css content creators on youtube, [Kevin Powell](https://youtu.be/5QIiWIoCmsc) has some great content, also [Traversy Media](https://youtu.be/sQUB039MG0I) has a decent one. Of cause there are alot more that do great tutorials but this is two that will help you out.